# Create arrays in array in a loop using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to lists:

```
a=[1,2,3]
```

and

```
b=[4,5,6]
```

I would like to create and array containing arrays of the two lists so I did

```
c=np.array([[a],[b]])
```

My question is:How can implement it in a loop? To create an empty array and then create arrays into the array?

Calling `c[1]` will return `array([[4, 5, 6]])`. How can I access e.g. the 5 into the array?

Comment: There is no array of `[4,5,6]`.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay I change the b

Answer (score 1):

c[1] would give `[[4 5 6]]` to access to 5 you should  `c[1][0][1]`

```
import numpy as np
b=[4,5,6]
a=[1,2,3]
c=np.array([[a],[b]])

print c[1][0][1]
```

**UPDATE**

It's easier to do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
b=[4,5,6]
a=[1,2,3,9] #I added an element to clarify how to manage indexes in case u have diff sizes
c=np.array([a,b])

#j= sum(1 for x in c if isinstance(x, np.ndarray)) Another way to see how many item in the list

for j in range(len(c)): #Selecting the list (a,b ..)
    i=0
    while i<=len(c[j])-1: #Looping in the list
        print "index (",i,",",j,"):",c[j][i]
        i+=1
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I do it in loop?

Comment: @DimKoim        Updated my answer below if this is what you had in mind :)

Comment: In addition to  hagubear's answer, I clarified how to loop and print all the elements. +I modified the example to show how to manage indexes in case u have diff sizes (Check UPDATE)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [4,5,6];
c = [a,b];

c[1][1] # Gives you 5
```

To do it in a loop

```
for z in [a,b]:
    c.append(z)

# continue as usual......
```

Also, you don't really need numpy to do this. If you do, follow @Taha s answer above.

Comment: Good to know :) Just remember that if you are planning to make portable python scripts using this, importing numpy is really something I don't recommend. Having good modules like numpy is good, but if this is not part of the standard python distribution then it might affect the portability and compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer

If the list of numbers are read into your program from an external source (aka file), your intended procedure is not recommended (and my answer is meaningless) because `numpy` provides a number of `i/o` functions that do this kind of job transparently and efficiently, e.g., [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

#### Procedure example

```
import numpy as np

r = [1,2,3]
s = [4,5,6]
t = [7,8,9]

arr = np.array([row for row in (r,s,t)])
print arr
```

*Output*

```
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]
```